# Deleting Array of LN

Tags: c++, arrays

Just wondering what's wrong with my attempts to delete this. Being that I have to use the variable declared by my professor as

```
LN** map = nullptr;
```

for the assignment I'm working on, using a simpler data type is not an option.

```
class LN { 
public:
    LN()                        : next(nullptr) {}
    LN (const LN& ln)           : value(ln.value), next(ln.next) {}
    LN (int v, LN* n = nullptr) : value(v), next(n) {}

    int value;
    LN* next;
};

int main()
{
    LN** array = nullptr;
    array = new LN*[5];
    int j=1;
    for (int i=0; i<5; ++i) {
        array[i] = new LN();
        array[i] = new LN(j++, array[i]);
        array[i] = new LN(j++, array[i]);
    }

// What I think should work, but doesn't.

    for (int i=0; i<5; ++i) {
        delete array[i];
    }

    delete[] array;
    array = nullptr;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In this case, there's a pretty obvious error, but you should explain *how* exactly it doesn't work (what do you expect to happen vs. what actually happens).

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your delete attempt here.  It will successfully delete all elements currently stored in the array followed by the array itself.

The problem is that the destructor of `LN` is not properly cleaning up all of the values in the list.  This is causing all of the `next` pointers to leak when the head `LN` value is deleted.  Try adding a destructor here

```
~LN() {
  delete next;
}
```

Comment: Disagree. `LN` does not allocate any memory, so it should not be cleaning it up.